# Python - UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 42-43: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, nlp, decoding

I am trying to make a Named Entity Recognition but when I create train data for this purpose I am getting this error, I don't know why is this happening and how can I fix this. I am getting the following error:

```
File "pycrfsuite\_pycrfsuite.pyx", line 312, in pycrfsuite._pycrfsuite.BaseTrainer.append
  File "stringsource", line 48, in vector.from_py.__pyx_convert_vector_from_py_std_3a__3a_string
  File "stringsource", line 15, in string.from_py.__pyx_convert_string_from_py_std__in_string
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 42-43: ordinal not in range(128)
```

And here is the part of the code.

```
if str(s_id) in tuple_data[current_fold]:
    if word in tag_dict.keys():
        tuple_data[current_fold][str(s_id)].append((word, pos_tag, tag_dict[word]))
    else:
        tuple_data[current_fold][str(s_id)].append((word, pos_tag, "O"))
else:
    if word in tag_dict.keys():
        tuple_data[current_fold][str(s_id)] = [(word, pos_tag, tag_dict[word])]
    else:
        tuple_data[current_fold][str(s_id)] = [(word, pos_tag, "O")]
for data in tuple_data:

    all_sents = list(data.values())
    test_size = int(len(all_sents) * 0.2)
    train_size = int(len(all_sents) - test_size - 1)
    train_sents = all_sents[:train_size]
    test_sents = all_sents[-test_size:]
    X_train = [sent2features(s) for s in train_sents]
    y_train = [sent2labels(s) for s in train_sents]

    X_test = [sent2features(s) for s in test_sents]
    y_test = [sent2labels(s) for s in test_sents]

    crf = sklearn_crfsuite.CRF(
        algorithm='lbfgs',
        c1=0.1,
        c2=0.1,
        max_iterations=100,
        all_possible_transitions=True
    )
    crf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: You have a character in your text that is not ascii.  I would bet it is one of the shaped quotation marks, or the special dash.

Comment: Read the following link about how to create a [mcve].  Without the data causing the error, we can only guess.  Also, Python 2 or 3?  There were big changes to Unicode handling between the two.